# JavaScript: Using IF statement along with navigator.onLine to check for internet connection

Tags: javascript, networking, navigator

I'm using the following script to check for internet connection. I want something to be done IF the result is 'online' or if the result is 'offline'.

```
<body>
  <p><span id="status">checking...</span></p>

<script>
var statusElem = document.getElementById('status')

setInterval(function () {
  statusElem.className = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
  statusElem.innerHTML = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';  
}, 250);
</script>
</body>
```

Any ideas? Basically i want to use an IF statement: IF online then, else..

Comment: ...Are you looking for `if(navigator.onLine) { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: No need for timers. The browser triggers global `online`/`offline` events whenever the `navigator.onLine` property changes.

Comment: it is better use ternary operator , I use them rather than if else

Comment: Reference for connectivity events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: Be aware that the "onLine" flag isn't a very reliable way to know whether the browser has internet connectivity.

Comment: @apsillers - Yes, that's all I'm looking for. Call you please show me how to use an if statement along with navigator.onLine?

Comment: @Pointy - can you please be more specific and explain why?

Comment: [This MDN page goes into some detail.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine) Basically different browsers support it differently, and in general while a `false` value fairly reliably means you're not online, a `true` value is not necessarily accurate. To put it another way, there's a significant potential for false positives.

Comment: @Pointy - I know why now. Because, it will only check if you are connected to a network, but you might have limited connectivity - hence, it will think you are connected, but won't know you don't have access to the WWW.

Answer (score 1):

Using your interval code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if(navigator.onLine) {
        statusElem.className = 'online';
        statusElem.innerHTML = 'online';
    } else {
        statusElem.className = 'offline';
        statusElem.innerHTML = 'offline';
   }
}, 250);
```

However, you could do the same thing more elegantly by using [`online`/`offline` event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events):

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
    statusElem.className = 'offline';
    statusElem.innerHTML = 'offline';
}, false);

window.addEventListener("online", function () {
    statusElem.className = 'online';
    statusElem.innerHTML = 'online';
}, false);
```

Comment: It won't work. Weird. It seems you can't use navigator.onLine along with IF statements.

Comment: You don't see the first code working? It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GwAZb/. (Note the conditions stated in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine): "In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is **not able to connect to a local area network** (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true... In Firefox and Internet Explorer, **switching the browser to offline mode** sends a false value. All other conditions return a true value." If using IE or Firefox, did you switch to offline mode?)